# internal link searching via org-open-at-point not working for me

Tags: org-mode

```
[[search for me]]
```

doesn't end up finding the text 'search for me' in the same org file (internal link), instead, it always says 'no match' and asks if I'd like to create a new headline. If the text 'search for me' is instead enclosed in double brackets, e.g.,

```
<<search for me>>
```

then the link above works. It shouldn't need double brackets to work. Perhaps I have something configured to interfere with the normal behavior? Not sure how to debug this. Any ideas what is happening? Does it work for you?

Comment: [[..]] looks for radio targets (the text in << >>) and then headlines I think. It does not does a plain text search as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JohnKitchin. The docs were somewhat ambiguous the way they are written IMO.

Comment: Please post any suggested improvements to the documentation on the org-mode mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

I created a few versions that work for me. Hopefully it will help someone else:

```
(defun my-org-search-link-regexp ()
  "Search an org link by text in the same file."
  (interactive)
  (if (org-in-regexp org-bracket-link-regexp 1)
    (let ((link-text (if (match-end 1)
                         (org-match-string-no-properties 1)
                       nil)))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (re-search-forward link-text nil t))))
```

or

```
(defun my-org-search-link-regexp ()
  (interactive)
  (when (equal major-mode 'org-mode)
      (let ((object (org-element-context)))
        (when (eq (car object) 'link)
          (let ((link (org-element-property :raw-link object)))
            (goto-char (point-min))
            (re-search-forward link nil t))))))
```

or

```
(defun my-org-search-link-regexp ()
  "If link under point is org link and of link type `regexp:',
e.g., regexp:search for this text, then search for the regexp supplied,
otherwise invoke org-open-at-point."
  (interactive)
  (when (equal major-mode 'org-mode)
      (let ((link-type "regexp:")
            (command-prefix-value)
            (object (org-element-context)))
        (when (eq (car object) 'link)
          (let ((link (org-element-property :raw-link object)))
            (when (>= (length link) (length link-type))
              (setf command-prefix-value (substring link 0 (length link-type))))
            (if (and command-prefix-value
                     (equal link-type command-prefix-value))
                (let ((link-regexp (substring link (1+ (length link-type)) nil)))
                  (org-mark-ring-push)
                  (goto-char (point-min))
                  (re-search-forward link-regexp nil t))
              (call-interactively 'org-open-at-point)))))))

(bind-key "C-c C-o" #'my-org-search-link-regexp org-mode-map)
```

My preference is the third one as it, combined with the keybinding, allows me to use my regular keybinding for org-open-at-point. There is probably a better way of doing this using an actual org link type datatype of something, but it works nicely for me. I don't want double brackets all over the place in my org files. I call org-mark-ring-push so that I can later call org-mark-ring-goto which I have mapped to evil-leader m B. This way I can reliably jump back to the originating link.